# How to write Batch SQL query in procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

if i want to write a procedure like below, is there some other way that,
to avoid using concatenate SQL statement, i am just afraid, if the input is too long, exceed the limit of max varchar, the code will have big problem.

Thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_ALL_STATUS
    @IDs varchar(MAX) = null,
    @status int = null
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IDs is null
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE mytable SET status = ' + @status + ' WHERE id in (' + @IDs + ')'
    EXECUTE @SQL
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of dynamic SQL (which is also vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and passing in a VARCHAR(MAX), consider using [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx):

```
-- Creates the TVP type - only needed once!
CREATE TYPE IntegerTableType AS TABLE 
( Identities INT );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_ALL_STATUS
    @IDs IntegerTableType READONLY,
    @status int = null
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE mytable 
    SET status = @status
    WHERE id IN
     (SELECT Identities FROM @IDs)

END
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) shows how to call these from your .NET code.

Comment: Hi Oded, thank you very much for the answer. One more question, after creating the new type, in C# code, i need to use SQL statement to invoke this procedure, but how can my code know the new type???

Comment: @shrimpy - There are a number of exampled here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Safe pattern for VARCHAR(MAX) lists in params. It does require STRING_SPLIT or equivalent function (SQL Server 2016 and higher. Not sure about other SQL flavors)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectSomeListOfIDs (
    @AnyDelimitedIDList VARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN

    --The idea here is to make the list creation flexible and non-brittle for non-technical users and external calls.  Overkill for most scenarios.  Depending on the expected data, some delimiters should definitely be taken out.
    REPLACE @AnyDelimitedIDList = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        @AnyDelimitedIDList
        ,CHAR(09),'|')  --Tab
        ,CHAR(10),'|')  --LF
        ,CHAR(13),'|')  --CR
        ,CHAR(44),'|')  --Comma
        ,CHAR(59),'|')  --SemiColon
        ,CHAR(58),'|')  --Colon
        ,CHAR(46),'|')  --dot
        ,CHAR(34),'|')  --DoubleQuote
        ,CHAR(39),'|')  --SingleQuote
        ,CHAR(32),'|')  --Space

    --this enables the input to never become executable code
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #IDList
    SELECT ID = x.value
    INTO #IDList
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AnyDelimitedIDList,'|') x
    WHERE ISNULL(x.value,'') <> ''

    --Obviates the need for Dynamic SQL 
    SELECT ID
    FROM dbo.MyTable x
    JOIN #IDList  list
        ON x.ID = List.ID --safe from sql injection 

    --Dynamic SQL is no longer needed for the sake of the ID List, but if Dyn is still needed/desired, the list can still be simplified and made safe:
    DECLARE @dummyScalar DATETIME = GETDATE()
    EXEC ('
        SELECT ID
        FROM dbo.MyTable x
        JOIN #IDList  list --safe from sql injection, and a bit simpler
            ON x.ID = List.ID
        WHERE x.date > '''+@dummyScalar+'''
    ')

END
```